# I want to make a 2D array in which the users will be able to input both strings and intergers as data

Tags: c

I want to make a 2D array in which the users will be able to input both strings and intergers as data. I want the first column to contain the name of each user and each row to contain their info, something like this;

```
name1(char) surname1(char)  height1(int) weight1(int)

name2(char)  surname2(char)  height2(int) weight2(int)

name3(char)  surname3(char)  height3(int) weight3(int)
```

I can't figure out how to input both types of data into one array.

Edit; This is for a homework exercise which asks for a multidimensional array.

Comment: Have you considered using a `struct`?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution could be storing that info in a struct better than managing multidimensional arrays.

Like

```
struct User {
 char name[NAME_SIZE];
 char surname[MAX_SURNAME];
 int height;
 int weight;
};
```

And then just having an array of `User` as follows:

```
struct User users[DESIRED_SIZE];
```

Comment: I should have specified in my original post that this is a task from a homework exercise, which specifically asks for a multidimensional array, so I can't use a struct instead.Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @philipnasus are you allowed to use structures inside a 2D array? I mean, you could create an struct with two fields, one for integers and other for strings, and then use only needed one ( in first two columns the string field, and in two others integer field), and then the 2D array containing this structure type in each field.

Comment: That would certainly make things easier but unfortunately I can't .

Comment: If you're not needing integers fields anymore (although functions as atoi are available) then use a 2D matrix containing arrays of char, and for storing integers use sprintf into a buffer for example, so in that way each field will contain strings.

Comment: Though this didn't meet the unwritten rules of the assignment, you get the nod for providing a struct example (even though it too could have been fleshed out a bit more). Any time you need to coordinate values of differing type as a single object, then a `struct` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be using structures but you can't. So using only arrays you can do this

```
char users[N][4][L];
```

Where `N` is the maximum number of users that you can store and `L` is the maximum number of characters for each field (name, surname, height and weight).

The problem with this array is that you read heights and weights as characters, so you would need to make a function to check whether the inputs satisfy you.

Here's a sample program -accepting only heights between 1 and 3 meters- that was written in a bad way on purpose, rewrite it properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 50
#define L 20

int alphaToInt( char *s );

int main() {

    char users[N][4][L];
    int height = 0;
    
    puts("Enter height please");
    
    while( ( scanf(" %s", users[0][2]) != 1 || (height = alphaToInt(users[0][2])) < 100 || height > 300 ) && puts("Try again please...") );

    printf("Height of user #0: %s\n", users[0][2]);
    
    return 0;
}

int alphaToInt( char *s )
{
    int n = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++) n = n * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
    
    return n;
}
```

Here's another way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 50
#define L 20

int checkMyAlpha( char *s );

int main() {

    char users[N][4][L];
    
    puts("Enter height please");
    
    while( ( scanf(" %s", users[0][2]) != 1 || !(checkMyAlpha(users[0][2])) ) && puts("Try again please...") );

    printf("Height of user #0: %s\n", users[0][2]);
    
    return 0;
}

int checkMyAlpha( char *s )
{
    int n = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++) {

        n = n * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
        if( n > 300 && (n = 1) ) break;
    }
    
    return n > 100;
}
```

Find your way.

Comment: He says he can't use multiple arrays. Strange assignment.

Comment: Oh thank you, I am going to delete the part of the 2 arrays

Comment: I generally also let the OP know that any time they end up with a design that uses a 3D array of anything, it is time to think about refactoring your approach. While there are unique cases where a 3D array is proper -- they are few and far between. It is an odd assignment, since `struct` is off limits -- so this may be the best you can do. Also, since no MCVE was provided, the question should be closed and additional details requested. (this is clearly a write-it-for-me question rather than a valid, "I'm stuck here" questions) But you have put good effort into the question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I should put a stop to my eagerness to make these little programs.

Answer (score 0):

1. What I suggest is to just use 4 different arrays for the respective field instead of a 2d array. Or you can use pair and assign one field to indicate whether it is integer or not.
2. Array of structure .

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use multiple arrays.This is from a homework exercise and it specifically asks for a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use arrays, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 char *persons[][4] = {
  {"Person", "One", "123", "456"},
  {"Person", "Two", "323", "756"},
 };

 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  printf("%s %s %i %i\n", persons[i][0], persons[i][1], atoi(persons[i][2]), atoi(persons[i][3]));
 }

 return 0;
}
```

The integer would be stored as a string, and you can use strlol to convert a string to an int. In C, you can't store mixed types in an array, unless if you want to use `void *`, but you probably don't want to go that route.

I used the above declaration of `persons` above to succinctly initialize the 3D array, but it may not make practical sense for your application. `char[]` creates a char array. It represents the above strings. The size is going to be the size of the characters in the initialization, so won't be able to add more chars to the end of the string. It might be better to do `char *persons[80][4]` instead. `char[][4]` creates an array of 4 of `char[]`; this represents 1 "row" in the above initialization. `*persons[][4]` points allows you to create an array of `char[][4]`.

Davide's does what you want. However, if you want to dynamically allocate the number of persons, it'll be better to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char Person[4][80];

int main() {
 Person *persons = malloc(2*sizeof(Person));

 strcpy(persons[0][0], "Person");
 strcpy(persons[0][1], "One");
 strcpy(persons[0][2], "123");
 strcpy(persons[0][3], "456");

 strcpy(persons[1][0], "Person");
 strcpy(persons[1][1], "Two");
 strcpy(persons[1][2], "323");
 strcpy(persons[1][3], "756");

 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  printf("%s %s %i %i\n", persons[i][0], persons[i][1], atoi(persons[i][2]), atoi(persons[i][3]));
 }

 return 0;
}
```

You don't need a typedef, but I couldn't get the code to compile just by using char. This is still one contiguous chunk of memory.

A struct is recommended:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Person {
 char *name;
 char *sur_name;
 int height;
 int weight;
};

int main() {
 struct Person persons[] = {
  {"Person", "One", 123, 456},
  {"Person", "two", 234, 567},
 };

 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  printf("%s %s %i %i\n", persons[i].name, persons[i].sur_name, persons[i].height, persons[i].weight);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Height and weight are likely to have decimals

Comment: He says height and weight are ints.

Comment: Oh I missed that

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Just a question tho.Why do you use the pointer char *persons[ ][4] instead of using an array?Sorry if this is a dumb question.